# Multiple paragraphs in html, autogenerated

Tags: html

`your text`

Is there a way to generate multiple lines in html at once with same classes? I know one can do p{This is a paragraph $}*10 but I want to have all of them 2 assigned classes like class1 class2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=,
    initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- I created several paragraphs in easy steps-->
    <!-- p{This is a paragraph $}*10-->

    <p>This is a paragraph 1</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph 2</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph 3</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph 4</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph 5</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph 6</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph 7</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph 8</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph 9</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph 10</p>

    <!-- but I want to make them look like this-->
    <p class="class1 class2">This is paragraph 1</p>
    


    
</body>
</html>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Emmet Cheatsheet](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/)

You should be able to do it like this:

```
p.class1.class2{This is a paragraph $}*10
```